# Перегрузка оператора сложения для дробей

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов, операторы

Пишу класс рациональных чисел. Хочу перегрузить оператор сложения, чтобы можно было складывать с дробями целые числа. Всё получилось, но проблема в том что возможна запись 
<мой класс> = <мой класс> + <целое число> 
Если же я пишу так:
<мой класс> = <целое число> + <мой класс>
всё крашится: no match for 'operator+' (operand types are 'int' and 'Number')

Вoт код в .h:

```
class Number {
public:
    Number(int numerator = 0, int denominator = 1);

    int getNumerator() {return this->numerator;}
    int getDenominator() {return this->denominator;}
    string toString();

    // определяем арифметические действия дробей с дробями
    Number operator+ (Number &other);
    Number operator- (Number &other);
    Number operator* (Number &other);
    Number operator/ (Number &other);

    // определяем арифметические действия дробей с целыми числами
    Number operator+ (int i);
protected:
    int numerator; // числитель
    int denominator; // знаменатель
};
```

Код в .cpp:

```
Number Number::operator+(int i) {
    Number res(i * this->denominator() + this->numerator(), this->denominator());
    return res;
}
```

Comment: ну все правильно _ вы же определили   Number operator+ (int i); Это означает, что вы можете написать выражение Number + int  и получить результат определяемой вами, а  int + Number  это другое выражение,  и можно так написать только если вы определили  operator int()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот в том числе и по этой причине такие операторы рекомендуется реализовывать не методами класса, как у вас, а отдельными (дружественными) функциями. Вы реализовали именно оператор сложения, в котором целое является *правым* операндом. Реализовать оператор сложения для целого числа в качестве *левого* операнда методом класса невозможно в принципе. Его в любом случае придется реализовывать обычной функцией.

Но тут на самом деле стоит сделать шаг назад и посмотреть на общий дизайн. Вам на самом деле *вообще не нужно* реализовывать операторы для сложения с целыми числами. Ваш класс `Number` уже обладает конвертирующим конструктором, который умеет преобразовывать целые числа в ваш `Number`. После этого ваши готовые операторы для операндов типа `Number` уже сами сделают все правильно. Для этого, однако необходимо 1) реализовать их обычными функциями, 2) не забыть о `const` в параметрах-ссылках, который у вас почему-то отсутствует.

```
class Number {
public:
    Number(int numerator = 0, int denominator = 1);

    // определяем арифметические действия дробей с дробями
    friend Number operator +(const Number &lhs, const Number &rhs);
    friend Number operator -(const Number &lhs, const Number &rhs);
    friend Number operator *(const Number &lhs, const Number &rhs);
    friend Number operator /(const Number &lhs, const Number &rhs);

protected: // <- ???
    int numerator; // числитель
    int denominator; // знаменатель
};
```

Такой класс уже сам по себе будет поддерживать

```
Number a(2, 3);
Number b = a + 1;
Number c = 25 + a;
```

и ничего для этого дополнительно писать не надо.

Если вам при этом захочется написать отдельные реализации для операций с обычными числами (например, в целях оптимизации) - вы можете это сделать. Но лучше это делать обычными функциями с двумя параметрами, как показано выше, а не методами класса.

Comment: не могу понять зачем кому то нужно будет наследовать такой класс?...

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan: Я изначально не обратил внимания. Не знаю, почему автор использовал именно `protected`.... Может просто опечатка.

Comment: ничего, а я изначально не обратил внимание на обьявление операторов ( с неконстантными аргументами). И по поводу того, что очень многие пишут в классе не +=, а +  и т. д.  " так много читаю такие коды, что уже не говорю об этом"

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Number {
    int numerator; // числитель
    int denominator; // знаменатель
    Number(int num = 0, int denom = 1)
        : numerator(num), denominator(denom) {}
    //...
    // определяем арифметические действия дробей с целыми числами
    Number operator+ (int i)
    { return  Number(i * denominator + numerator, denominator); }

    friend Number operator +(const int i, const Number& N)
    { return  Number(i * N.denominator + N.numerator, N.denominator); }
    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& os, const Number& N)
    {
        os << N.numerator << " / " << N.denominator;
        return os;
    }

};

int main()
{    
    Number test(4, 2);
    std::cout << 5 + test;
    return 0;              // теперь все нормально!
}
```

просто оператор определите и еще можете при возвращении Number производить еще и  сокращение дроби... и не нужно делать данные закрытыми, если вы всеравно обеспечиваете доступ ко всем данным! Если вам удобно, то вы можете не определить int + Number, но в кодах написать не 5 + Number, а Number(5) + Number...

Comment: да, я даже не обратил внимание на обявление остальных операторов